# Tabular DAX - best way to get min date in calendar regardless of context

Tags: powerbi, dax, tabular

I have a typical rolling 12 months Dax measure as :

```
R12M :=
CALCULATE (
    [Income],
    DATESBETWEEN (
        Calendar[Date],
        NEXTDAY ( SAMEPERIODLASTYEAR ( LASTDATE ( Calendar[Date] ) ) ),
        LASTDATE ( 'Calendar'[Date] )
    )
)
```

The problem is that our Calendar table only starts from a certain date, so anything which is in the first year does not link to the calendar. So I want to start the measure from a year after the minimum date on our calendar. What is the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

I hope you found your answer by now, but in case still looking then try like,

```
R12M :=
CALCULATE (
    [Income],
    DATESBETWEEN (
        Calendar[Date],
        NEXTDAY ( SAMEPERIODLASTYEAR ( LASTDATE ( Calendar[Date] ) ) ),
        LASTDATE ( 'Calendar'[Date] )
    ),
    FILTER ( CALENDER, DATE >= DATEADD ( FIRSTDATE ( DATE ), 1, YEAR ) )
)
```